# Where can I find documentation on why `this` context is undefined when assigning object method's as DOM event handlers in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events, this

It seems that React components change the behavior of how `this` is assigned in DOM event handlers, but I cannot find any documentation that details this behavior.

For example, when using an object's method as a DOM event handler with vanilla JS, the `this` context remains as the object:

```js
function SomeClass() {}
SomeClass.prototype.showThis = function() { console.log(this) };
let o = new SomeClass();
```

```html
<button onclick="o.showThis()">Show "this"</button>
```

React, however, changes this behavior such that the `this` context becomes undefined:

```js
function SomeClass() {}
SomeClass.prototype.showThis = function() { console.log(this) };
let o = new SomeClass();

function App() {
  return (
       <button onClick={o.showThis}>Show this</button>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Where is the documentation that explains this?  (I can surmise why this may occur, but would like to know where this is covered in the React docs.)

Comment: React is not doing that. `{o.showThis}` passes a reference to the function to be used as the handler, but the relationship to object `o` is lost. That is normal JavaScript behavior.

Comment: The normal JavaScript example I provided does not result in this.  What would be an example of a normal JavaScript example that does do this with an object's method?

Comment: That's because a function will be constructed *around* the string you pass in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not anything special to React. This is due to the fact that, with the inline handler, the moment the function gets invoked, it's being invoked as part of an object:

```
onclick="o.showThis()"
         ^ object
                   ^^ invocation
```

But in the React code, it's not being invoked as part of an object - rather, `o.showThis` is passed as a *callback* which is then called like any other callback - like `callback()` or something of the sort (and not as part of an object). If you very slightly tweak the code so that the `showThis` is invoked as part of an object, it'll show the same behavior as the inline handler:

```
onClick={() => o.showThis()}
               ^ object
                         ^^ invocation
```

```js
function SomeClass() {}
SomeClass.prototype.showThis = function() { console.log(this) };
let o = new SomeClass();

function App() {
  return (
       <button onClick={() => o.showThis()}>Show this</button>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

So there's nothing for React specifically to explain about it - it's a behavior of the underlying JavaScript.

You would similarly get `undefined` in the inline handler if the function was called not as part of an object, and you were in strict mode.

```js
'use strict';

function SomeClass() {}
SomeClass.prototype.showThis = function() {
  console.log(this)
};
const o = new SomeClass();

const theFn = o.showThis;
```

```html
<button onclick="theFn()">Show "this"</button>
```

Comment: "But in the React code, it's not being invoked as part of an object - rather, o.showThis is passed as a callback."  I guess my question is why wouldn't the fact that in React it's passed as a callback not qualify as something React specific and that React docs should explain?  I suspect you're saying it's plainly obvious that this must be happening - and I suspected it was based on the behavior - but I'm not clear why this is a given.

Comment: Because `()` is not present at the place where it's referenced as part of the object, it must be a callback - just like `const theFn = o.showThis;` puts `showThis` into a different variable name that's not connected to the `o` object. The same sort of thing would apply to any library. `someLibraryFunction(someObject.someMethod)`, if it ever calls `someMethod`, will not call it with a `this` of `someObject` because the place where it's invoked doesn't reference `someObject`. Now, if it were invoked at a point where it was part of an object, it'd be a different story - but it isn't.